# Is there any program like deep freeze for Debian allowing installations and compilations?

Tags: debian, software-installation

I researched and found some similar programs to deep freeze for Linux, not yet tested any program but the descriptions they leave not install programs on the operating system or am I wrong?

Does anyone have experience with this you can give me this tip and help me with this? I need something similar to the deep freeze, a way to return to the original state of the files whenever I restart the machine or login to the ssh, that would be possible? And let me install programs and compiling programs without restrictions.

The goal is to have a clean machine so I perform several tests of compatibility and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Tough one. The only product I know in Linux that works like deep freeze is Lethe. In Windows the alternatives are endless, the free alt being Reboot Restore Rx.